# Can't send res.send back without getting errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

I must be missing something majorly important here

```
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  let posts = await loadPostsCollection();
  console.log(await posts.find({}).toArray());
  res.send(await posts.find().toArray());
});

async function loadPostsCollection() {
  const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, {
    // useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  return client.db("stack_1").collection("posts");
}
```

why do i get headers already sent error?

Express js @latest
MongoDb Atlas free cluster
db with single item in a 'posts' collection
I must be missing something incredibly simple.

The console log works as intended...
I'm pretty sure all my async await calls are at the right place...

Help..?

EDIT : ERROR:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/posts: 2020-07-23T23:57:06+03:00
[ { _id: 5f19e338adcae71eca1c3658, name: 'liad', status: 'active' } ]
(node:7894) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:536:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/media/liad/Data/liad_dev/vue-express-mongo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/media/liad/Data/liad_dev/vue-express-mongo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/media/liad/Data/liad_dev/vue-express-mongo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/media/liad/Data/liad_dev/vue-express-mongo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at /media/liad/Data/liad_dev/vue-express-mongo/server/routes/api/posts.js:10:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:7894) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7894) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Edit 2:

refactored everything to use mongoose

I get the same error !

```
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    desc: req.body.desc,
  });
  console.log(post);
  post
    .save()
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json({ message: err });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the error too? Also you shouldn't be connecting to mongo inside a request. It'll be cool doing that at the global scope

Comment: I'll edit it right now :)

Comment: I believe it's due to the ``await`` are inside ``res.send()``, which means it might not passing the actual value into it. Try to put it outside and store the result in a variable, and pass the result to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

The way I've defined my application is trying to dynamically access my routers without having to define them one by one

```
let routerPath = "/api/members";
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let routerPath = req.path;
  app.use(`${routerPath}`, require(`./routes${routerPath}`));
  next();
});
```

My error was caused because I've had an extra next();

```
let routerPath = "/api/members";
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let routerPath = req.path;
  next();
  app.use(`${routerPath}`, require(`./routes${routerPath}`));
  next();
});
```

For some reason that wrecked my app...

Thanks for trying to help everyone

Answer (score 0):

in the second occurence of  posts.find there is no empty object as argument. Could that be an issue?
Also it would be safer to put the function bodies of async functions in a try/catch block as exceptions are not catched right now.

Comment: Nope, not the issue, I've refactored everything to use Mongoose...And I still get the same error (using a different tutorial even!)
```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    desc: req.body.desc,
  });
  console.log(post);
  post
    .save()
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json({ message: err });
    });
});
```